# PHP preg match?

Tags: php, regex, find, preg-match

Okay, let's say this is a line
v1=something;v2=something2;

how to get v1 value (something) starting from = and break at ; and same to be done with v2 by calling it (v1)

```
function getVal($name){
  // some code to start grabbing from = and end by ;
}
```

when i call

```
getVal("v1");
```

it should return "something"

Comment: You don't need regexp you need `split`

Comment: You don't need split you need regexp :)

Comment: Note that you should rather use a [summary as question title](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help7). If you are more specific there, it gets easier to find for others, and attracts more specific help instead of just anyone curious for mysterious headlines. Eschew relisting tags, redundant pleas for help, question marks without question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

v1=([^;]*)

The match will be in group 1

Just replace v1 in the regex with the key you want to lookup

```
if (preg_match('/v1=([^;]*)/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v(?:\d*)=(\w;+)
```

That will match all v (with digits or no digits after it) and then the match group will be after the = sign. It is group 1.

Comment: @VIPINJAIN Then it can also contain a `!` or a `|` or `™`. The asker didn't specify any other requirements other than letters, and I'm assuming they can update the regex themselves if they encounter special characters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$line = "v1=something;v2=something2;";

function getVal($name, $line){
    preg_match('/'.$name.'=([^;]*)/', $line, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
} 

echo getVal("v1", $line);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are obliged to sent the line to your function (or you can be dirty and use it as global).
So, your function can be something like that :

```
<?php
function getVal($name, $line){
    // some code to start grabbing from = and end by ;
    preg_match('#;?' . $name . '=([^;]+);?#', $line, $aMatches);
    if(isset($aMatches[1])) {
        return $aMatches[1];
    }
    return false;
}

$line = 'v1=something;v2=something2';
$v1 = getVal('v1',$line);
echo $v1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Function:

```
function getVal($name, $line){
    preg_match("/{$name}=(.+);(v(\d+)=|$)/U", $line, $matches);
    $matches = $matches[0];
    $matches = preg_replace("/{$name}=/","",$matches);
    $matches = preg_replace("/;v(\d+)=/","",$matches);
    return $matches;
}
```

this will give you exact answer.

Tested and working.:)